# Time to install minitab using Wine

Tags: macos, wine, minitab

I am installing Minitab16 using WineBottler 1.4.1.6. The installation has been going for over 2 hours now. The dialog box says "Creating Minitab.app". Has anyone done this before? Any idea how long it takes?

Comment: I'm curious to know if this worked out for you? I need Minitab for one of my grad program classes and will probably be trying something similar to what you have here.

Comment: It did not. I used a virtual box and installed windows

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the reply. The virtualbox solution is what I have now and was hoping that wine would be better but it sounds like I should stick to what I have.

Comment: Have you tried using strace or ltrace or other tracing tools to see what WineBottler is doing?

Answer (score 0):

It has probably errored out. Nothing besides resource depriving game applications should use enough memory to take 2 hours, or some kind of relentless scan. I would suggest running it directly, it will still save most information for your next use.